# Creating javascript array correctly using JSTL for:each

Tags: javascript, arrays, jstl

I am trying to create an array object based on data that came from the servlet since trying to c:if with a Javascript variable was invalid. The session variable 'preeditList' is an array of 3 fields.   Here is the following array in my JSP:

```
  var checkedArray = 
      [
        <c:forEach items="${preeditList}" var="preeditList" varStatus="status">  
           {"schedulekey": '${preeditList.getCHK_SCHEDULE_NUMBER()}',
            "contractkey": '${preeditList.getCHK_CONTRACT_YEAR()}',
            "prevStatus": '${preeditList.getCHK_STATUS()}' 
           }
           <c:if test="${!status.last}">    
           ,    
          </c:if>  
       </c:forEach>  
     ]  ;
```

This is giving me lots of syntax errors saying that a comma is expected.   First of all should the array come out looking like this or completely screwed up:

```
 var checkArray = [
    {
     "schedulekey": "43080",
     "contractkey": "2016",
     "prevStatus": "RP"
     },
    {
     "schedulekey": "43070",
     "contractkey": "2016",
     "prevStatus": "CP"
     } 
    ]  ;
```

If this is fine then what I wrong on my syntax to pull this off.

Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var countries = [
<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="country" varStatus="status">  
    {country: '${country.name}',
    provinces : [ 
        <c:forEach items="${country.provinces}" var="province" varStatus="provinceStatus">  
           '${province.name}'
           <c:if test="${!provinceStatus.last}">    
             ,    
           </c:if>   
        </c:forEach>  
    ]}
    <c:if test="${!status.last}">    
      ,    
    </c:if>  
    </c:forEach>  
];
```

Other Way :

```
var countries = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="country" varStatus="status"> 
    countryDetails = new Object();
    countryDetails.country = ${country.name}; 
    var provinces = new Array();

        <c:forEach items="${country.provinces}" var="province" varStatus="provinceStatus"> 
           provinces.push(${province.name});
        </c:forEach> 
    countryDetails.provinces = provinces;
    countries.push(countryDetails);
</c:forEach>
```

OutPut:

```
var countries = [
  {country:"USA",
  provinces: [
    "Ohio",
    "New York",
    "California"
  ]},
  {country:"Canada",
  provinces: [
    "Ontario",
    "Northern Territory",
    "Sascetchewan"
  ]},
]
```

I found solution from Problems ..... [JSTL To JS](http://code.shouttoday.com/2016/02/how-to-change-java-list-into-js.html)